# Calling external application from IOS 9 webview with Nativescript

Tags: ios, webview, nativescript-vue

I'm trying to open external application from webview on IOS 9 and I keep getting this error.

```
ispmobile://param?TID=enter_your_id

-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "ispmobile://param?TID=enter_your_id" - error: 

"This app is not allowed to query for scheme ispmobile"
```

When I looked around, apparently there is a restriction from IOS 9 and on when calling external app and the solution that I was pointed to was to implement LSApplicationQueriesSchemes in the info.plist.

```
info.plist

<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<string>ispmobile://</string>
```

I have done that and i still get the "This app is not allowed to query for scheme ispmobile" error
Any suggestions on how to fix this?

thanks in advance